# java scanner hasnext(pattern) conflicts with white space

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I wrote this regex `([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} -> ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}` to match srt time formats like `00:16:31,600 -> 00:16:35,700` and it works fine when i use it like this: `someString.matches(timeSpanPattern)` but when i use it in a `hasNext(pattern)` like the following code it always returns false and i thinks it's because of whitespaces before and after `->`. is there any alternative or codes to prevent this? i tried `useDelimiter` function but it didn't work(maybe i'm using this function incorrectly)

```
final String timeSpanPattern = "([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} -> ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}";
.
.
.

Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");

while (i.hasNext(timeSpanPattern)) {
    line = i.next(timeSpanPattern);
    forbiddenTimes.add(line);
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usage of `useDelimiter` function is incorrect. You(i) should use it in this way:

```
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
i.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Comment: This will work, but the way you had it originally is better.  In fact, it's the preferred approach.  This is why `useDelimiter()` returns a reference to the Scanner it was called on: so you can daisy-chain it with the constructor.

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks, you mean `useDelimiter returns `this`, something like jQuery functions that we can use like `$('selector').func1().func2().func3()....;` but i don't know why it didn't work in this way and when i accidentally separated this line it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

Reread your question and I found the actual problem:

```
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
```

Line separator is `"\n"` on UNIX systems, `"\r\n"` on Microsoft Windows systems.

Comment: so java takes white space as token terminating character by default but i want it to match the whole line with pattern...

Comment: hmmm! that's a better way to do it!